# oracleの外部結合表現(+)からleft joinへの書き換えがうまくいきません

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

現在oracleで使用しているsql文をsqlserverで使えるように書式を変更しています。
そこで、以下のようなsql文について、書き換えを試みているのですが、
select結果が同じになりません。

(+)を利用したsql文の挙動が理解できておらず、
申し訳ありませんがご教示いただきたいです。

**書き換え元--oracle--**

```
SELECT 
A.id,
A.name,
B.address,
C.tel1,
C.tel2,
D.sex
FROM TBL_A A,TBL_B B,TBL_C C,TBL_D D
WHERE 
A.id = '000001',
A.id = D.id,
A.id = B.id(+),
A.id = C.id(+),
B.address = C.address(+),
B.customer_name = D.customer_name(+)
```

上記のように内部結合して、
複数テーブルで(+)を用いた外部結合をするsqlを
left joinを使用したsqlに書き換えたいのですが、
select結果が異なってしまいます。

どのように書き換えるのが正解なのか教えていただきたいです。

以下のような単純な書き換えは理解できるのですが、
複数(内部結合と外部結合の組み合わせ)が全く分からず。。

(+)での外部結合

```
SELECT 
A.id,
B.address
FROM TBL_A A,TBL_B B
A.id = B.id(+)
```

left join 書き換え

```
SELECT 
A.id,
B.address
FROM TBL_A A 
LEFT JOIN TBL_B B
ON A.id = B.id
```

以上、お分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示ください。
また、不足している・分かりにくい点がありましたら
ご指摘ください。修正させていただきます。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: あまり正規化されていないように見受けられるのですが、B.id・C.idは存在しない可能性があるもののD.idは存在するということでしょうか？

Comment: 申し訳ありません、上の例で書いているsqlについては仮で適当に書いてしまっています。整合性は考えず、例の書き換え元をleft join に置き換えた時、どういった表現になるかが知りたいと思っています。もし、実際のsqlに近いものが必要ということであれば、修正させていただきます。いかがでしょうか。。

Comment: では回答者には何を答えてほしいのでしょうか？ `(+)`は`LEFT OUTER JOIN`に変換できることは質問文に既に記載の通りだと思いますが…。

Comment: 2テーブルのみの外部結合の変換は分かりますが、書き換え元のsqlについては、内部結合と外部結合(3テーブル以上)を使用していると思います。その場合はどうなるのかを知りたく、書き換え元をleft joinを使用したものに変換したらどうなるのかを回答お願いしたいです。

Comment: 書き換え元が実行できない構文なので、正しい SQL を例示してもらえますか。WHERE 句をカンマで繋いだり、TBL_C が TBLA からも TBL_B からも外部結合していると実行できません。

Answer (score 2):

基本的な1対1の外部結合を理解されておられるようですので、1対nの外部結合は**外部テーブル(今回のテーブルAに該当)に複数の`left join`できる**ことを応用すれば解決できるはずです。

第三者への有益な情報を目指して簡単なところから記載します。
記載されているSQLは質問と若干違います。MySQLのテーブル構成および実行結果は[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c37421/8)のリンク先を参照してください。

なお質問にある変換前のOracleのSQLは多重外部結合なので`Oracle 11g`以前では下記の**エラーが発生**して動きません。

> ORA-01417: 表が少なくとも1つの他の表に外部結合されている可能性があります。

SQL Fiddleは11gが対象で例示できないため、冗長ですがwith句でテーブルを代用しています。
もちろん実行は12c以降で行ってください。

#### A left outer join on B

まずはテーブルAとBを結合します。(既に質問で例示されているSQLと類似しています)

```
-- 2 tables in Oracle
with  A as
     (select 1 id, 'name1' name from dual union all
      select 2 id, 'name2' name from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'name3' name from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'name4' name from dual union all
      select 5 id, 'name5' name from dual)
     ,B as
     (select 1 id, 'customer1' customer_name, 'address1' address from dual union all
      select 2 id, 'customer2' customer_name, 'address2' address from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'customer4' customer_name, 'address4' address from dual)
select   A.id, name,
         B.address
from     A, B
where    A.id = B.id(+)
order by A.id
```

```
-- 2 tables in SQL Server
select   A.id, name,
         B.address
from     A
         left join B on A.id = B.id
order by A.id
```

#### A on B, C

次に複数テーブルの外部結合です。
テーブルAとBに加えてテーブルAとCも外部結合します。
`left join`を複数行積むことで、1つの外部テーブルに複数のテーブルを連結できます。
まだテーブルBとCは結合していません。

```
-- A on B, C in Oracle
with  A as
     (select 1 id, 'name1' name from dual union all
      select 2 id, 'name2' name from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'name3' name from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'name4' name from dual union all
      select 5 id, 'name5' name from dual)
     ,B as
     (select 1 id, 'customer1' customer_name, 'address1' address from dual union all
      select 2 id, 'customer2' customer_name, 'address2' address from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'customer4' customer_name, 'address4' address from dual)
     ,C as
     (select 1 id, 'address1' address, 'tel1' tel from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'address3' address, 'tel3' tel from dual union all
      select 5 id, 'address5' address, 'tel5' tel from dual)select   A.id, name,
         B.address,
         C.tel
from     A, B, C
where    A.id = B.id(+)
and      A.id = C.id(+)
order by A.id
```

```
-- A on B, C in SQL Server
select   A.id, name,
         B.address,
         C.tel
from     A
         left join B on A.id = B.id
         left join C on A.id = C.id
order by A.id
```

#### A on B, C and B on C

そろそろ厄介なところで、Oracleでも12cでようやく(+)が対応したSQLです。
とは言えANSI準拠の外部結合ならば、AとCの結合条件にandを加えてBとCを結合するだけです。

```
-- A on B, C and B on C in Oracle 12c-
with  A as
     (select 1 id, 'name1' name from dual union all
      select 2 id, 'name2' name from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'name3' name from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'name4' name from dual union all
      select 5 id, 'name5' name from dual)
     ,B as
     (select 1 id, 'customer1' customer_name, 'address1' address from dual union all
      select 2 id, 'customer2' customer_name, 'address2' address from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'customer4' customer_name, 'address4' address from dual)
     ,C as
     (select 1 id, 'address1' address, 'tel1' tel from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'address3' address, 'tel3' tel from dual union all
      select 5 id, 'address5' address, 'tel5' tel from dual)
select   A.id, name,
         B.address,
         C.tel
from     A, B, C
where    A.id = B.id(+)
and      A.id = C.id(+)
and      B.address = C.address(+)
order by A.id
```

```
-- A on B, C and B on C in SQL Server
select   A.id, name,
         B.address,
         C.tel
from     A
         left join B  on A.id = B.id
         left join C  on A.id = C.id
                     and B.address = C.address
order by A.id
```

#### A, D and A on B on C and A on C and D on B

最後にこれまでの内容を踏まえてテーブルDを結合します。
AとDをwhere句で結合するとBとDのleft joinでエラーになるので、inner joinでAとDを先に等価結合しておきます。

質問のSQLとは異なりますが、B on DでBを外部結合すると、Bにないレコードが消えて外部結合の意味が薄れるので、D on BでDを外部結合しています。
また外部結合であることを示すため、Dのcustomer_nameとsexにnullが入っているレコードがあります。

```
-- A, D and A on B on C and A on C and D on B in Oracle 12c-
with  A as
     (select 1 id, 'name1' name from dual union all
      select 2 id, 'name2' name from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'name3' name from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'name4' name from dual union all
      select 5 id, 'name5' name from dual)
     ,B as
     (select 1 id, 'customer1' customer_name, 'address1' address from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'customer3' customer_name, 'address3' address from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'customer4' customer_name, 'address4' address from dual)
     ,C as
     (select 1 id, 'address1' address, 'tel1' tel from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'address3' address, 'tel3' tel from dual union all
      select 5 id, 'address5' address, 'tel5' tel from dual)
     ,D as
     (select 1 id, 'customer1' customer_name, '1' sex from dual union all
      select 2 id, 'customer2' customer_name, '2' sex from dual union all
      select 3 id, 'customer3' customer_name, '3' sex from dual union all
      select 4 id, 'customer4' customer_name, '4' sex from dual union all
      select 5 id, 'customer5' customer_name, '5' sex from dual)
select   A.id, name,
         B.address,
         C.tel,
         D.sex
from     A, B, C, D
where    A.id = D.id
and      A.id = B.id(+)
and      A.id = C.id(+)
and      B.address = C.address(+)
and      B.customer_name = D.customer_name(+)
order by A.id
```

```
-- A, D and A on B on C and A on C and D on B in SQL Server
select   A.id, name,
         B.address,
         C.tel,
         D.sex
from     A
         inner join D on A.id = D.id
         left join B  on A.id = B.id
                     and D.customer_name = B.customer_name  -- D on B
         left join C  on A.id = C.id
                     and B.address = C.address
order by A.id
```